# Do equations like $y = \sqrt {x} \cdot 0$ have real solutions for $x<0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What I mean by the title, is that some equations, such as $y=\frac1x$ or $y=\sqrt{x}$ don't have any real solutions for some values of $x$. My question is:

> Does multiplying such functions by zero (ie $y=\sqrt{x}\cdot0$) make it so they have no solutions for those values (in this case $x<0$), are undefined, or that all values of $x$ are had the solution $y=0$?

If it depends on the function that is being multiplied, how would one know which one is correct?

Sorry if it is a bit of a dumb question, but I could genuinly not find the answer (except for the case $y=\frac00$, which is undefined (y can have any value))

Comment: When multiplying by $0$ you should do it in both members of the equation, so you get $0=0$ which doesn't add anything new

Comment: I meant multiplying to right side of the equation to get a new equation :)

Comment: In some contexts it is allowed to say $\langle undefined\rangle\cdot0=0$, but the context should be well delimited with very careful definitions.

Comment: could you explain what you mean specifically with "some contexts"? Could you give an example of such a context?

Comment: Now I get your point, what I would say is no, the domain of $y=0\sqrt{x} $ is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ so your function will really be $f:\Bbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in its domain. A similar thing happens with $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ which is $1$ but it is not defined on $x=0$ (although you can define it there continuously).

Comment: So what you're saying is that the function multiplied by zero still has the same domain, and is thus undefined for values outside that domain? @JoseSquare

Comment: Yes thats what I'm saying, when multiplying two functions the domain of the new function is the intersection of their domains. It is true that the new domain could extended continuously, but that will be another function

Comment: Thank you! Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yes I'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiplying two functions, the new function domain will be the intersection of the domains of the two functions although the domain could be continuously extendable, but that would be a new function.

In you example as $f: \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow  \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$
 and $g: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ with $g(x)=0$ the product function will have 
$\Bbb{R} \cap \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}= \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ as domain.

Answer (score 0):

$y=0$ is the only solution to the equation $y(x) = \sqrt{x} \cdot 0 = 0$ of unknown $x$. $y$ is a constant. However, I am not sure if you ask for the domain of $\sqrt{x}$. Well, it has a definition for negative reals, but I am not sure you are talking about that.

So if $\sqrt{x}$ is the one that goes from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$, then it's not defined. However wise, for $\sqrt{x}$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, it is defined.

However, in general, if you don't mention the definition of squareroot, we will assume that it is the complex one if you are dealing with negative reals.

Comment: Maybe $\sqrt{x}$ was a bad example as it does indeed have complex solutions for $x<0$. I'm wondering if the same applies to functions which do not have any solution for certain values (ie does multiplying a function by zero change its domain?)

Comment: No, it doesn't change its domain because the initial equation is defined with an operator that doesn't have a part of the total domain.

Comment: I'm rather confused by that comment, could you rephrase?

Comment: If $g(x) \cdot a$, it doesn't change its domain, even if $a$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean, does an equation like $$\sqrt x\cdot0=0$$ for example, have *real* solutions different from the real solutions of $$\sqrt x=0.$$

The answer is that $\sqrt x\cdot0=0$ has infinitely many solutions, namely all nonnegative real $x,$ whereas the latter has only $0$ as solution. I assume all through that we never leave $\mathbf R,$ otherwise the first equation has imaginary solutions for *all* real numbers, even negative ones.

All this follows from the meaning of square root of $x,$ which is a number $r$ satisfying $$rr=r^2=x.$$

Comment: No, that is not at all what I'm asking. I'm asking if $y=\sqrt{-1}*0$ has a real solution (assuming $\sqrt{-1}$ is undefined - only real numbers.

Comment: @Treehee Since you don't want to work with $i,$ then an equation involving $i$ would be undefined, too.

Answer (score 0):

actually the function you defined is only defined for x greater or equal to zero, and the value is 0. but if you define the function y=0, it yields the same values for x>=0 and also values for x<0. so you extended the function to a bigger domain, which is a common practice in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,

$$0\cdot\sqrt{x}$$ is undefined for negative $x$. Multiplication by $0$ "comes too late".