# Domain of a function having the product of two square root functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given a question regarding finding the domain of the following function on my test:

$y=\sqrt{x-2}\sqrt{x-5}$

I came up with the following answer: $[5, \infty)$

---

However to my surprise, my teacher was (and is) claiming that the answer should be $[5, \infty) \cup \{2\}$

He says that when $x = 2$, $y=0$ but that doesn't make any sense to me as in that case $\sqrt{x-5}$ is clearly not defined. I am unaware of the correct answer...

Comment: The domain is indeed $[5,+\infty)$.

Comment: I agree with you.  There's no "multiply by $0$" exception for undefined terms.

Comment: I also agree with the previous comments, and suggest that you print out this webpage and show it to your teacher.  This is a case of cart before the horse.  Each factor on the RHS must be well defined in order to compute the value of the LHS.  In Real Analysis, rather than Complex Analysis, the expression $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x - 5}~$ is undefined for $~x < 5.~$  This makes it *game over*.

Comment: Related: [Do equations like $y = \sqrt {x} \cdot 0$ have real solutions for $x<0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3119948/89922)

Comment: @JulioPuerta @ lulu @ user2661923 Okay, thank you sirs. Thank you so much. I was looking for some verification. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks, sir. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3119980/1178192 This answer was quite helpful and same is the case with the comments on this post. Thanks, everyone. Have a nice day.

Comment: @peterwhy In a sense it does, but it could still be helpful I guess......not sure tbh. If you say we can delete my question. Or better I may rephrase it a bit so that people like Doug don't oversee the intended function and simplify it to lose the original domain.

Comment: I can also confirm that we cannot multiply $0$ with an undefined expression. Your solution is correct.

Comment: And doug's solution is invalid since $\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ only holds for non-negative real numbers $a,b$.

Comment: @Peter Thanks sir....I should note that in my textbook...I am still a student. Thank you sir.